# Phalcon - how to get last updated timestamp of a table

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

Could you please advise me a way to get last updated timestamp of a table from information_schema table in Phalcon.
I have taken a look at the Model\Metadata but it doesn't give me what I need.
I also looked into implementing a raw mysql query, but I feel like it is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [updating-records](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#creating-updating-records) or if you can set before save recode like [this](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#events-and-events-manager)